# Nadaraya-Watson regression alternative for binary outcome

Tags: regression, nonparametric, binary-data, nadaraya-watson

I am looking for pointers as to what would be the non-parametric equivalent of Nadaraya-Watson regression when modelling a binary outcome. I have been googling and ended up with Generalized Additive Models, but I think these impose functional forms?

Comment: "Nonparametric" has a pretty loose definition, but isn't Nadaraya-Watson already considered nonparametric?

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the reply. Yes, NW is non-parametric, but not suited for binary outcomes. That's why I asked what would be the binary outcome alternative.